# Basic & Common doubts regarding Android background services

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-application

I have certain questions regarding background services in Android:- 
1). I am creating an app that requires doing some work in the background periodically. By background, I mean that even if the application is closed (swiped from App Drawer or phone is rebooted or anything). So what is the best way to implement this? I am good at coding in Android as well as Flutter. So even a high-level overview would be helpful. 
2). Will the solution eat up a lot of battery or will it be just like WhatsApp or other applications which keep giving notifications regularly?

It would be very helpful if the solution provided works perfectly with the latest versions of Android. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no reliable way to do background jobs.
But there are some workarounds.

This is my solution:

In your class extending Application:

```
private AlarmManager awakeAlarmMgr;
private PendingIntent awakeAlarmIntent;

public void startBackService() {
        
        Log.d(TAG,"BACK SERVICE STARTED")

           
        // START ALL SERVICES
        startStepService();
        startLocationService();
        setAllReminders();

        // SET AN ALARM TO KEEP ALL SERVICES ALIVE
        startStayAwakeAlarm();
       
    }


private void startStayAwakeAlarm() {

        awakeAlarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        if(awakeAlarmIntent!=null)
            awakeAlarmMgr.cancel(awakeAlarmIntent);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StayAwakeReceiver.class);
        awakeAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        awakeAlarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, awakeAlarmIntent);
    }
```

In StayAwakeReceiver.java:

```
public class StayAwakeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG,"STAY AWAKE!!!");

        AppController.getInstance().startBackService();

    }
}
```

Don't forget to declare the receiver in your Manifest:

```
        <receiver android:name=".receiver.StayAwakeReceiver" />
```

And call `startBackService()` in your Application's onCreate

Comment: I'm aware of it. Basically, this service ends after it finishes it's assigned work, & to keep it alive, we just restart it, right?
I am assuming there's a better way to it.